# ¿Cómo saber cuantos días tiene un mes con php?

Tags: php, html

estoy tratando de hacer un select con los días de un mes, pero para saber cuantos días van a haber en el select debo saber cuantos días tiene el respectivo mes, el problema es que no sé como hacerlo ya he intentado `date('t', strtotime($fecha))` que fue un metodo que vi, pero no resultó, espero que puedan ayudar, gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto te puede ayudar

```
<?php
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003); // 31
echo "There were {$number} days in August 2003";
?>
```

Te dejo tambien 2 links

https://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691142/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-the-current-month-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Obtienes los datos del mes y el año actuales y luego los pasas como parámetros a la función `cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mesActual, $anioActual);`

```
$anioActual = date("Y");
$mesActual = date("n");
$cantidadDias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mesActual, $anioActual);
echo $cantidadDias;
```

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, encontré un método que me gustaría compartirles

```
$first_day = mktime(0,0,0, "02", "01", "2019"); //Calcula el primer día del mes que sería el 02
echo date('t', $dias); //Calcula el ultimo día y lo imprime
```

Los parametros de este metodo serían así `mktime($hora,$min,$seg,$mes,$dia,$anio)`
Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

utiliza la función date de PHP

```
$DiasMes= date('t');
```

donde 't' devuelve el número de días del mes en curso

En este blog hay un ejemplo de como utilizarlo espero te funcione.

https://codigoroot.net/blog/obtener-fecha-y-hora-en-php-con-date/#parametrosDate

Answer (score -1):

```
$dia = substr($desde, 8); 
$numMes = date("M", strtotime($desde)); 

$dia2 = substr($hasta, 8); 
$numMes2 = date("M", strtotime($hasta));
```